# image alignment of uploaded image in WYSIWYG

Tags: wysiwyg, media

Sorry if this is an easily solvable question but I am struggling to get to grips with Drupal (this is my first attempt with this cms)

I am using Drupal 7 and have installed CKEDITOR (as well as required modules). I have also enabled an inset image field that is shipped with Drupal (sorry I don't know the correct terminology).

My issue is that when I insert the image URL into the image info > URL field, resize the image and select align the image does not align as requested (although in the preview text box it displays as expected)

For example

**align image right**

displays several lines of text then a large gap and the image sitting 2/3rd's along the first line of code displayed after that gap. Remaining text is displayed as expected

Looking at the html there is no class attribute being applied to the image. Do I need to enable something or do I need to alter the code of the module im using? either way where do I need to start looking?

EDIT

After further investigation I have found CKEditor is stripping the style attribute that has been added. After searching for a solution to this issue I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349048/ckeditor-strips-span-and-style-attributes) and applied the solution but it has made no difference. Are there any other alternative solutions? (other suggestions are also in a very similar vein)

Comment: how about adding extra CSS for your case since your problem is just layout.

Comment: Sometging in ckeditor strips out style tags and I assume it wull also strip out class tags. I would try this but dont know how to change the behavoiur to check my theory

Comment: depending on your setup - my toolbar has align buttons, so I just select what I want to align then click the button. If you go to source or plain text mode you can see it puts its own class on it.